# How to find all files containing a string?

Tags: command-line, grep, find

I'm using this

```
# cat *.php* | grep -HRi error_reporting
```

This is my result

```
(standard input):$mosConfig_error_reporting = '0';
(standard input):error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

How can I find out what files contain the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-l` option to show the file name only:

```
grep -il "error_reporting" *php*
```

For the recursion, you can play with `--include` to indicate the files you want to look for:

```
grep -iRl --include=*php* "error_reporting" *
```

But if you want to show the line numbers, then you need to use `-n` and hence `-l` won't work alone. This is a workaround:

```
grep -iRn --include="*php*" "error_reporting" * | cut -d: -f-2
```

or

```
find . -type f -name "*php*" -exec grep -iHn "error_reporting" {} \; | cut -d: -f-2.
```

The cut part removes the matching text, so that the output is like:

```
file1:line_of_matching
file2:line_of_matching
...
```

From `man grep`:

> **-l**, --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  the  name of each input
>   file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning
>   will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
>
> **--include=GLOB**
>
> Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
>   matching as described under --exclude).
>
> **-n**, --line-number
>
> Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its
>   input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: Thanks but I need recursion and filepaths

Comment: Sure! Just updated @totalitarian . The `--include` option should work. Let me know if it does to you!

Comment: Thanks, that just prints out a list of php files

Comment: @totalitarian and is it your expected output? This is what I understood from your question.

Comment: Sorry it should include the line with the match on as well

Comment: @totalitarian ah right then you can add the `-n` flag. Updating.

Comment: @totalitarian can you indicate what exact command are you using?

Comment: @totalitarian ok what I see is that `-l` (L) and `-n` are not compatible. So let's try with this one: `grep -iRn --include="*php*" "error_reporting" * | cut -d: -f-2`. The `cut` part removes the matching text. I also like `find . -type f -name "*php*" -exec grep -iHn "error_reporting" {} \; | cut -d: -f-2`.

Comment: Sorry I inadvertently fixed the issue so can't test anymore. I'll mark it as correct though